# SQLite query aggregation

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two columns of data in a SQLite table: `users` and `URL`. I'm trying to construct a query that returns the `users` with a particular `URL`. I'm trying the following:

```
SELECT url, COUNT(url) as RESULT 
FROM bookmarks 
GROUP BY url 
order by RESULT desc
limit 10;
```

This query is close, but I only get back one user—not an aggregation of all the users for a given bookmark URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) to get a list of users for every `url`

```
SELECT url, 
       COUNT(users) as RESULT, 
       group_concat(users) as user_list
FROM bookmarks 
GROUP BY url 
order by RESULT desc 
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and for more details:

```
SELECT ... GROUP_CONCAT(users ORDER BY users ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS user_list
FROM ...
```